# Heat-Equation with different initial values

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I look for the solution for the heat-equation with the initial value problem $(\mathbb{I})$:
$u(0,x)=f(x)=\begin{cases} B,  & \text{if }x\ge 0  \\  A,  & \text{if }x<0 \end{cases}$

Now i can't understand, why i just can solve the initial-value problem $(\mathbb{II})$
$u(0,x)=g(x)=\begin{cases} -1,  & \text{if }x\ge 0  \\  +1,  & \text{if }x<0 \end{cases}$
with solution $u(t,x)$

and then $\frac{1}{2}(A-B)u(t,x) +\frac{1}{2}(A+B)$ solves problem $(\mathbb{I})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u$ be the solution of $(\mathbb{II})$ and
$$
v(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}\,(A-B)\,u(t,x) +\frac{1}{2}\,(A+B).
$$
Then
$$
v_t-v_{xx}=\frac{1}{2}\,(A-B)(u_t-u_{xx})=0,
$$
so that $v$ is a solution of the heat equation. The initial conditions are
$$
v(0,x)=\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{2}\,(A-B)+\frac{1}{2}\,(A+B)=B & \text{if }x\ge 0,\\
\frac{1}{2}\,(A-B)+\frac{1}{2}\,(A+B)=A & \text{if }x<0. \end{cases}
$$